# What is the name of this chart element?

Tags: terminology, data-visualisation

[image]

What is the name for these vertical bands in this graph?

Comment: how about Bins?

Comment: could call them segments or sections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little late to this party, but in my neck of the woods, it is called a **plotband**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As shown, the chart elements could be referred to generically as ***intervals*** or time ***periods***.

The duration of each of them is implied to be one twenty-four hour civil day beginning at midnight during a sequence of days.

The implication of the number is that some measured event achieved this (peak) value during the specific 15 October interval.

As there are also Month and Quatar [sic] buttons, the chart elements would have variable proportions and relative sizes to portray the data consistently with the overall term for the sequence selected.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a line graph with segments. This visualization of it just has the axis labels taken off.

More specifically it's the interactive version where you can visualize individual data segments on the line with your cursor.

Answer (score -1):

That's a line graph laid over a column or bar chart.

Each vertical element is a bar, or column. When all the bars are the same height it's a timeline.

Each vertical section is a day so the columns are in calendar format.

You can call each vertical section a section, a node, a day, a bar, a column, a block, an element, a value, a data item or a chart element.